# infomation in company about stoarge and /services/data/v32.0/limits is different?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I have doubt regarding /services/data/v32.0/limits  about storage and company information storage details ? Why is not same? can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API and storage limits are the same if you convert to byte first by multiplying by 10^6 followed by division by 2^30 or

```
(StorageLimit*10^6)/2^30
```

based on this I can conclude that the API displays the volume in base10 or mixed while the UI seems to display base2 volume
see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte for reference

Comment: Thanks Gilhil for reply but its also showing same value as for version v32.0.

Comment: I did some testing and it seems like they display the limit in mb(but where 1mb = 1000000 byte) in the rest api. After i added 6 zeros and converted from byte to gb i got the same values

Comment: My org storage is 256.0 MB and from  /services/data/v39.0/limits , I am getting  268MB. Can anyone clarify this differnce?

Comment: if you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte then you can see that the API displays the volume in base10 or mixed while the UI seems to display base2 volume